# Помогите найти ошибку в коде и добиться моей основной цели(сделать игру)

Tags: javascript

Надо сделать игру на отгадывание числа:

> Продолжаешь отгадывать одно и тоже число пока не отгадаешь

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
  'use strict';
  do {
    num = prompt('Игра: отгадай число от 1 до 100', 0);
  } while (num == a && num);
  const a = (Math.random() * 100000) % 100;

  if (num == a) {
    alert('Угадал!');
  }
  if (num > a) {
    alert('Твой ответ больше задуманного числа! Попробуй еще!', '');
  }
  if (num < a) {
    alert('Твой ответ меньше задуманного числа! Попробуй еще!', '');
  }
</script>
```

Где здесь ошибка???

Comment: Мне надо сделать игру на отгадывание числа - выводит окно: ошибаешься и продолжаешь отгадывать одно и тоже число пока не отгадаешь

Comment: `while (num == a && num);
 const a = (Math.random() * 100000) % 100;`
 чему `a` будет равна в `while`?

Comment: Здесь везде ошибка :) Все же просто - просто надо отойти от компа и подумать

Comment: поясню, вы сперва используете значение `a`, а только потом присваиваете рандом?

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть несколько недочетов: инициализация переменной `a` до использования (иначе с чем вы сравниваете), также вам нужна работа в цикле до тех пор, пока значение, введенное пользователем, не совпадет с рандомным.

```
const a = (Math.random() * 100000) % 100; // инициализировать a    
do {
    let num = prompt('Игра: отгадай число от 1 до 100', 0);
    if (num == a) {
        alert('Угадал!');
    } else if (num > a) {
        alert('Твой ответ больше задуманного числа! Попробуй еще!', '');
    } else if (num < a) {
        alert('Твой ответ меньше задуманного числа! Попробуй еще!', '');
    }
} while (num !== a && num); // пока значения не совпадут
```

Comment: У тебя не то что я хочу, мне надо если я ошибся, то компьютер дает мне еще одну попытку и так далее пока я не отгадаю

Comment: `while (num !== a)` здесь как раз мы и проверяем, совпали значения или нет. В условии сказано, что цикл выполняется пока значения не совпадут или пока вы не отгадаете

Comment: @azlov, num всегда `!==a`, потому что num - это строка, а `a` - число